# How to use Assimp library in Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, assimp

I am trying to load 3D model in Android using Assimp library.  Can anybody guide me how to use Assimp liberary to load a 3D model in Android device?

Comment: Hey .Can you find solution for this ? please write answer.